# Detectar touch a la izquierda o derecha en celular (JAVASCRIPT O JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera saber si se puede detectar el gesto de arrastrar a la derecha la pantalla o a la izquierda para cambiar de pestaña (tal cual lo hace whastapp cuando quieres pasar de chat a estados o a llamadas

De antemano gracias

Comment: Tienes esta librería de JQuery Mobile: https://jquerymobile.com/
En ella encontrarás los eventos que mencionas

Comment: Con Javascript puro, hay un ejemplo [aquí](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents3.shtml)